# How User account be locked for 30 min after 5 unsuccessful login attempts with asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net membership provider for managing users. I have a requirement to lock user accounts for 30 mins after 5 unsuccessful attempts. How should I do that using asp.net membership provider on the server side?

Also I want that 'Passwords should expire after 3 months', 'Last 10 used passwords should be remembered'. Is there any way to solve these requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `SqlMembershipProvider` then use

`maxInvalidPasswordAttempts` for attempts

`passwordAttemptWindow` for locking for specified period

no option for password expiration or password history

but if you are using `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` then use

`maxInvalidPasswordAttempts` for attempts

`passwordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration` for locking for specified period

and ajust your domain policy for password expiration or password history

full info here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingthesqlmembershipprovider

Comment: The MembershipUser object has a property called LastPasswordChangeDate you can check for password expiration after the user has logged in.  Doesn't solve the history problem, though.

Comment: passwordAttemptWindow is for checking the invalid password. It is not a locked out period. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordattemptwindow(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For the first requirement, the membership provider offers a [MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property which you can use in conjunction with the [PasswordAttemptWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordattemptwindow.aspx) property.

The 2nd requirement to the best of my knowledge would require you to customize the membership provider. The base membership provider does not retain prior passwords or have a forced password reset to my knowledge. This could be done if you create a custom provider yourself however.

[Starter material for creating a custom membership provider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Answer (score 0):

ASp.Net membership provider doesn't provide any built in support for your requirements, still you can achieve them by doing some custom work.i-e

1. You can schedule a job that unlocks all locked user accounts, every 30 minutes.
2. In your application you can put a check if subsequent user logins are 3months apart, the user should be redirected to changepassword page.
3. Last 10 password of the user can be kept in another table, for which you need to write some code on change password functionality.

Comment: 1. What if the user was locked 29m after last schedule job?

Answer (score 0):

you can do all the above mentioned functionalities by creating proper tables in database.
i.e.,

1. create one table to store count of wrong attempts, increment count when wrong attempt occurs based on the primary key i.e user name, within 5 attempts if he logs successfully then try to make that count to null
2. While locking the user after 5 unsuccessful attempts store the time and write one script to check that time continuously, when it meets 30mins call unlock method
3. For password also take day count, i.e., from changed date, each time when user logs in after checking user validity check for password day count if it cross 3days prompt them to change
4. If you are taking user name as primary key, create one more table to store max 10 passwords for each user, while inserting password to this table(when user changes his password),check the table for number rows for that user if it is 10 then based on the last lesser date you can delete that row and insert new password and you can compare new password with old passwords also while inserting

Comment: deepika nice solution its always better to rely on our own database architecture and functionality i like your way@devjosh

Comment: welcome i love to stick to the basic features always because we can customize the things according to our logic.@happy programming

Answer (score 0):

Create custom membership provider. There You can implement all needed functionality, see sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx